# what is the use of Csinglelock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

It is mentioned in MSDN, that to lock and Unlock CCriticalSection object, we should use CSingleLock. But CCriticalSection::lock() and CCriticalSection::unlock() does the same thing, doesn't it? Then What is the difference between both the methods?

Comment: It's too large a subject for a simple answer, but you should learn about [exception safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) and [RAII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511). What would happen if something threw an exception between `lock` and `unlock`? How is a destructor different from an explicit function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a wrapper will ensure that (almost) no matter what you do from the point where you are locking the lock, when you leave the function, it will unlock.

Consider:

```
void func()
{
    lock();
    ... plenty of lines ... 
    // x = 8128 happens on a Wednesday, in a month without 
    // r in the name, only if the day is divisible by 7 and 3. 
    if (x == 8128)
       return;
    ... more lines of code ... 
    unlock();
}
```

So, once every now and again, your application forgets to unlock the lock.

The same applies if you get an exception, use goto, etc.

If you use a wrapper, you are guaranteed that the destructor will be called when the scope of the wrapper ends. This is just as useful for `std::string` or `std::vector` as it is for locks.

Of course, it won't help if you use for example `longjmp` to jump out of the context. But then you shouldn't be using `longjmp`!